# Coset multiplication for non normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

The coset of **a** multiplied by the coset of **b** is defined as the coset of **ab**. Is it true even for cosets of non normal subgroups ?

Comment: That only makes sense for normal subgroups.

Comment: You can show for a non-normal subgroup that at least one such multiplication will be ill-defined.

Comment: This is why normal subgroups are considered here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H\leq G$ be a subgroup, and denote $[a]$ the coset of $a$. You want the formula $[a][b]:=[ab]$ being valid, which means that for any $h,h'$ in $H$, $[ahbh']=[ab]$, which rewrites as $ahbh'=abh''$ for some $h''$ in $H$, which rewrites again as $b^{-1}a^{-1}ahbh'=b^{-1}hbh'$ is in $H$ for all $b$ in $G$ and $h,h'$ in $H$. If $H$ is not normal in $G$, you can find a $l$ in $H$ and a $g$ in $G$ such that $g^{-1}lg$ is not in $H$. Then $b=g,h=l$ and $h'=e$ are a choice showing that multiplication can not be defined in this case.